# How to get a laravel route group to work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes, laravel-5.5

I am trying to set up a Laravel route group in Laravel 5.5 and use it in a blade. However I am getting the a Route not defined error. The full error is :

> "Route [admin/route_group_test] not defined. (View: C:\Users\Joey\Web\jrd_dnd_tools\resources\views\layouts\navigation.blade.php) (View: C:\Users\Joey\Web\jrd_dnd_tools\resources\views\layouts\navigation.blade.php) (View: C:\Users\Joey\Web\jrd_dnd_tools\resources\views\layouts\navigation.blade.php)

I have looked through the documentation and it looks like I am doing it right. Here is the line from the route file:

```
Route::prefix('admin')->group(function(){
     Route::get('route_group_test','AdminController@testingMiddleWare');
});
```

and the link from the blade:

```
{{route('admin/route_group_test')}}
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`route()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-route) helper uses route's name. From [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-route):

> The `route` function generates a URL for the given named route

So you need to [name the route](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#named-routes):

```
Route::get('route_group_test', 'AdminController@testingMiddleWare')->name('admin.route_group_test');
```

Or:

```
Route::get('route_group_test', ['as' => 'admin.route_group_test', 'uses' => 'AdminController@testingMiddleWare']);
```

And then use it:

```
{{ route('admin.route_group_test') }}
```

Or you can use unnamed route:

```
{{ url('admin/route_group_test') }}
```

Comment: I had to set the name to admin/route_group_test instead of admin.route_group_test. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'admin','namespace'=>''], function () {
    Route::get('route_group_test','AdminController@testingMiddleWare');
});
```

Comment: Use the below command and check if your route exist in this list 'php artisan route:list'